# Parse a string of an entire struct

Tags: c#, c++, parsing, reflection, t4

I got a string which holds an entire definition of a C++ native struct (That means the ENTIRE struct - name, fields, enums but without methods in it, in the same syntax as you would simply write the struct on your own).

What I need to do is take the string and convert it to a string representing the Managed C++ type of the native type.

The parsing and handling of the string is done with C#.

I am looking for a way and a library perhaps which makes it easy to do what I need.

I was thinking of somehow create a template and edit it with the data from the given native struct.

If you got an answer please divide it into 2 cases - The case in which I DO NOT have access to the project/dll where the native struct itself is defined (which means it needs to be a pure parsing of the string) and to a case in which I do have access, in which I might be able to somehow use reflection?

Comment: How would you imagine your code to treat custom classes and structs inside the parsed struct?

Comment: @Tarec: Like `string type = "int"; $type n; // makes an int` :-)

Comment: I asked about custom classes and structs, not basic value types. Unless you assumed it'll contain only the basic types.

Comment: what do you mean custom classes and structs?
The struct can of course definitions of other structs but it doesn't matter since all I need is just creating a string with that type.
In cases like this for example, I can assume that if I have an inner struct named "MyNativeStruct", then I'll convert it's name to "MyNativeStruct_M"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a T4 template. I made a template of a a managed C++ struct and parsed the native struct line be line and got the info needed about members and such and then inserted it to the T4 template.